# How to download, save, and load images with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I know Picasso can download and cache images automatically, but if I restart my phone, and I don't have internet, how can I access the same images?

Here is my implementation

```
// Picasso doesn't process URIs as strings, but as files
if(songObject.albumArtURI != null){
    File f = new File(songObject.albumArtURI);

    Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
            .load(f)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blackcircle)
            .into(viewHolder.albumArt);

// If songObject doesn't have URI but it has a URL do this     
} else if(songObject.albumURL != null){

    Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
            .load(songObject.albumURL)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blackcircle)
            .into(viewHolder.albumArt);

// Otherwise download the URL    
} else {

    String JSONURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=michael+jackson";

    getRequestQueue();

    GsonRequest<SongInfo> myReq = new GsonRequest<SongInfo>(
            Request.Method.GET,
            JSONURL,
            SongInfo.class,
            null,
            createMyReqSuccessListener(songObject),
            createMyReqErrorListener());

    mRequestQueue.add(myReq);

    Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
            .load(R.drawable.blackcircle)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blackcircle)
            .into(viewHolder.albumArt);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know: If you use OkHttp for the HTTP requests, Picasso will use the internal http cache of okhttp for loading the images from disc.

Comment: If the image(using Image Url) is download and cached, then if you restart or internet is connected image will loaded from cache using the same code you used for downloading.

Comment: @VipulAsri But cache is wiped from memory on restart. Need long term storage solution.

Comment: Are you sure, that your images are added to the picasso disc cache? Use case: Start your app and load images. -> Kill your app with task manager -> Go offline -> Start your app again. -> Images should be loaded (if you have the indicators enabled, you should see a blue triangle in the left upper corner). If your images are not shown, I guess they are not added to http cache. In this case post your http request and the response headers, I assume wrong caching information.

Comment: @Christopher The problem is that after I restart my phone, I have to download the images again. I was hoping for a long term storage solution. I don't have any problem closing and re-opening the app with task manager.

Comment: @the_prole: I tried restarting my phone with my implementation. It simply works, the images are shown with the blue triangle. Either you have an option enabled to clean up your caches on reboot or your images are not cached. I think you should show some of your code as well as the http response for an image.

Comment: @Christopher Okay, I added my implementation, but where do I add `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` because I only get errors trying to add it.

Comment: Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
      picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
      picasso.load(f)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blackcircle)
            .into(viewHolder.albumArt);